# Laravel Eloquent - include related columns in query results

Tags: join, laravel, eloquent, fluent

**Objective:**
Return a composite response from my query, containing columns from both related models using Eloquent so that I can use Form::model to restore field values for User values AND Addresses values in my view. I want all the data in a single object and I don't want to use compact or otherwise manipulate the data if I don't have to.

**Tables:**

```
users (id, userWorkAddressID, ...)

addresses (ID, ...)
```

**Models**

**User**

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Address', 'ID', 'userWorkAddressID');
}
```

**Address**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id', 'userWorkAddressID');
}
```

**Things I've tried**

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

This just returns user data - no address data

```
$user = User::find($id)->address
```

This just returns the address for the user, but no user data

```
$user = User::with('address')->find($id);
```

This returns the user data, no address data

```
$user = User::with(array('address' => function($query){
    $query->addSelect(array('id', 'addressLine1'));
}))->find($id);
```

This also returns only the user data, no address data

I could just use Fluent, but do I have to?

How can I use Eloquent to join those two tables and return a single object consisting of the fields I represent in my view?

Comment: `$user = User::with('address')->find($id);` should actually work. The address model should be nested inside the `address` property

Comment: As @lukasgeiter said, it will work, if you eager load the related model (for `belongsTo`, `hasOne` and other -to-one relations). Just make sure you use array (`Form::text('address[some_field]',...)`) notation.

Comment: And your relations are wrong - 2nd param is always foreign key, so probably not `ID`

Comment: @lukasgeiter - That's what I thought, too, but there is no [address] property on my resulting object. Instead, I just have all fields from my users table.

Comment: @user2063125 That's probably because the relation is set up wrong. See Jarek's comment.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - corrected the arguments in my Address model so it's now: return $this->belongsTo('User', 'userWorkAddressID', 'ID'); No change. What would I have to do to eager load the related models? Is that why related data is not returned?

Comment: @user2063125 you are not showing the code that is building the form so it's hard to tell where you made a mistake.. Of course I assume you have the related object in place.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk - you were right. had them wrong in both models. now i see an 'address' property. thanks you both for your help!

Comment: No problem. @JarekTkaczyk are you gonna write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off your relations are wrong. Change both to:

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Address', 'userWorkAddressID', 'ID');
}
Address

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'userWorkAddressID', 'id');
}
```

then probably you will see the related model. Just remember to:

1 **Eager load the related model**: `$user = User::with('address')->find($someId);

2 use **array notation for related model** properties in the form: `Form::model($user, ..)` `Form::text('address[city]', ...)`